# Getting error on Create Table using UTF-8

Tags: sql, sqlite

my code is exactly this in "line.sql"

```
CREATE TABLE haltestellen (
id integer primary key autoincrement,
name varchar(64)
);
```

when i open sqlite3.exe and type ".read line.sql" i get this:

[Screenshot](http://www.pictureshack.us/images/89291_error.png)

quite strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a Unicode Byte Order Mark. Check the options in your text editor to save the file without a byte order mark, or save it in a different encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The query itself works. See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1ac10). You probably have an invisible special character at the beginning of your file.

Comment: thats so strange because i can't see any chararcter.. tried different programms.